# JavaScript: (How) can one retrieve external CSS rules in Chrome's DevTools?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, cors, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on a little Chrome extension that extends its DevTools. For this, I need to acquire all of the defined CSS selectors for the currently selected element (`$0`).

I know each item within `document.styleSheets` exposes all of the necessary data through `cssRules`. This would be perfect, but unfortunately CORS seems to throw a spanner in the works. For external stylesheets, `cssRules` returns `null`.

Is it possible to access this data without resorting to a hackish solution, e.g. downloading the stylesheet and inserting it into a `style` tag? I ask because Chrome itself seems to do so in its **Styles** sidebar panel, but I can't find much information on the matter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured it out. It just took a bit more digging in the documentation.

The `inspectedWindow` API exposes `getResources`, allowing you to fetch all of the resources within the inspected window. This includes type and functionality for fetching its content.

Injecting this content into a `style` tag allows you to access the CSS rules via `document.styleSheets`. This is ideal because my sidebar pane is encapsulated within a shadow DOM, allowing me to know exactly which stylesheets have been injected.

```
chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.getResources(function(resources) {
    for (var i = 0; i < resources.length; i++) {
        if (resources[i].type != 'stylesheet') {
            continue;
        }

        // inject the resource into the shadow DOM
        // this allows us to freely access all CSS rules CORS-free
        resources[i].getContent(function(content) {
            var style = document.createElement('style');
            style.textContent = content;
            document.body.appendChild(style);
        });
    }
});
```